# Mixed Authentication in ASP.NET Core (Windows and AAD JwtBearer)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, windows-authentication

I'm working on .Net 5 Web application that should have both Windows and Azure Active Directory JwtBearer authentications. One controller will use one windows authentication and another authentication will be for other controllers. It is clear how to set one or another, but I'm not sure how to set both of them.

For Windows authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

For Azure Active Directory JwtBearer authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
      .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

It seems that I can't set multiple authentications in AddAuthentication method and I'm wondering can we have several authentications at the same time at all? I would like to set them somehow in Startup.cs and have an controller attribute with authentication scheme.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class JwtBearerProtectedController : ControllerBase
...
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class WindowsAuthProtectedController : ControllerBase
```

**UPDATE:**
By trial and error I've found Startup configuration that works for both Windows authentication and AAD bearer authentication.

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

services
   .AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddAzureAdBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
```

Comment: I'm currently use 3 authentication schemes on one of my projects (1 I customize myself, one for Jwt standard system and one for hand-generate jwt on another system on node-js). So the answer is just simple, yes, we can and it works.

Comment: Did the document provided below solve your problem sir? If not, what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely have multiple auth options

I'd like to direct you to this msft doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-5.0

[image]